# Groupby by two differents options simultaneously

Tags: python, pandas

Good morning.

I've a pandas dataframe like the following:

```
df = 
     p   f   c     a
 0   1   2   1    16.32
 1   1   2   2    48
 2   1   2   3    60
 3   1   2   4   112
 4   1   2   5    52
 5   1   3   6   288
 6   1   4   7   201
 7   1   4   8    52
 8   1   4   4    44
 9   1   5   7   251.2
10   1   5   9   220
11   1   5   8    83
12   1   5  10   142
13   2   1  11   100
14   2   1  12   110
15   2   2  11   120
16   2   2  13   130
17   2   3  13   140
18   2   3  14   150
19   2   4  12   160
```

And I want to do a groupby along columns c and a, but grouping c using something like SQL's COUNT(DISTINCT) and grouping a using sum(), in a way my result will be:

```
df_result = 
    p   f   c      a
0   1   2   5    288.32
1   1   3   6    576.32
2   1   4   8    873.92
3   1   5  10   1570.12
4   2   1   2    210
5   2   2   3    460
6   2   3   4    750
7   2   4   4    910
```

But I can't reach that result trying differents combinations of groupby and stack.

**EDIT**
Take into account that column 'c' stores ID numbers, so the ascending order is just an example, so max aggregate wouldn't work. Sorry for don't say it before.

I think that a possible solution would be split it in two differents dataframes, grouping and then merge, but I'm not sure if this is the best solution.

Thanks you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need aggregate `list` and `sum` first, then call [`DataFrame.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html):

```
df = df.groupby('f').agg({'c':list, 'a':'sum'}).cumsum()
print (df)
                                                   c        a
f                                                            
2                           [154, 215, 1, 8000, 214]   288.32
3                      [154, 215, 1, 8000, 214, 640]   576.32
4      [154, 215, 1, 8000, 214, 640, 780, 830, 8000]   873.32
5  [154, 215, 1, 8000, 214, 640, 780, 830, 8000, ...  1569.52
```

And last get length of unique values per lists:

```
df['c'] = df['c'].apply(lambda x: len(set(x)))
df = df.reset_index()

print (df)
   f   c        a
0  2   5   288.32
1  3   6   576.32
2  4   8   873.32
3  5  10  1569.52
```

EDIT:

```
df = (df.groupby(['p','f']).agg({'c':list, 'a':'sum'})
        .groupby('p').apply(np.cumsum))
df['c'] = df['c'].apply(lambda x: len(set(x)))
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
   p  f   c        a
0  1  2   5   288.32
1  1  3   6   576.32
2  1  4   8   873.32
3  1  5  10  1569.52
4  2  1   2      210
5  2  2   3      460
6  2  3   4      750
7  2  4   4      910
```

Comment: I don't know why, but when I try this my column c looks like 5, 6, 9, 13; so it
is not making a distinction between whether the values ​​are repeated or not

Comment: Doing df.groupby('f', as_index=False).agg({'c':'nunique', 'a':'sum'}).cumsum(), the result for column 'a' is perfect, but column 'c' shows 5, 6, 9, 13 instead of 5, 6, 8 ,10

Comment: I explained it in my post edit: that numbers are ID numbers, and df.c is just an example. You can think that `df.c = [154, 215, 1, 8000 , 214, 640, 780, 830, 8000, 780, 910, 830, 10]` instead of `df.c = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,4,7,9,8,10]`

Comment: In group 4 you should get 8 because have 1 repeated element (8000 in my last example), and I want not count repeated values. In the same way, in group 5 you have 2 repeated values (780 and 830 in my last example)

Comment: I think that this really fits my desires! Thanks you very much. Just another question: 
what would happen if I had another column, 'p' for example, with which I also had to group as with 'f'?

Comment: @Á.Garzón - then change `df.groupby('f')` to `df.groupby(['f', 'p'])`

Comment: Yes, that was my first thought, however, the list sum 'propagates' along column p :(

Comment: @Á.Garzón - Can you change data with expected output?

Comment: @Á.Garzón - I understand now, need `cumsum` by first level `p` - need `apply` + `cumsum`, check edited answer.

Comment: Yeeees, I think that now it's perfect! Thanks you very much @jezrael, you strongly help me.